# How to name my classes?

Tags: php, oop

I have a base user class which is responsible for manipulating the basic user information: name, age, location, etc. I want to extend my system with the groups functionality and later with projects and meetings. For example:

```
class User
{
    public function getName() {
        ...
    }

    public function getAge() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then extend it with groups functionality:

```
class GroupableUser extends User
{
    public function join($groupId) {
        ...
    }

    public function leave($groupId) {

    }

    public function requestGroupInvitation($groupId) {
        ...
    }

    public function acceptGroupInvitation($groupId) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The name GroupableUser seems weird to me, however it does't make sense to add join and leave methods to Group class, because its user that joins and leaves a group, not the other way around.

And later I would have classes like **UserThatCanHaveProjects** and **UserThatCanParticipateInMeetings**. 
How to name these classes?

And how do you typically deal with these situations?

Comment: UserThatCanHaveProjects and UserThatCanParticipateInMeetings sound more like User properties than classes

Comment: userTeam or teamUser might be alternative class names to GroupableUser, but surely Group (or Team) as an independent class with a collection of User members

Comment: @Mark Baker That's why I am asking how to name these classes properly.

Comment: Usually I've found that names that identify capabilities of a class are usually applicable as interfaces. In other words, you might have a GroupableUser interface which a class can implement to identify that it has that capability. This may or may not be of use in your situation.

Comment: I agree with that. Make a simple User class, then make GroupableUser and UserWithProjects interfaces, and then a SystemUser that inherits from all. Although maybe those two interfaces are overkill, and should be only attributes of the base User class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The capability to participate in groups/meetings and have projects is something that a user might be able to *do*, but it's not something that defines what a user *is*. This is a pretty clear sign that modelling these options with additional classes is not a good design choice.

### Static approach #1: interfaces

In a statically typed language a simplistic implementation would look something like

```
interface IGrouppableUser {
     public function join(...);
}

class GroupableUser implements IGrouppableUser {
     public function join(...) { /* implementation */ }
}
```

And the consumers of grouppable users would accept `IGrouppableUser`, allowing you to craft as many classes as necessary. You can also do this in PHP, but as mentioned earlier it's probably not a good design no matter what the language.

As a footnote, I should add that with the addition of [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) to the language starting from PHP 5.4 the above scenario can be implemented a bit more conveniently (classes can use a trait instead of implementing an interface, which means you don't need to copy/paste the implementation of `join` all around the code base). But conceptually it's the exact same approach.

The main disadvantage of this approach is that it does not scale. It might be OK if you only need two or three types of users.

### Static approach #2: "not supported" exceptions

If most of the users are grouppable and can have projects then it doesn't make much sense to create a hellish hierarchy of classes; you can just add the necessary members to class `User`, making it a [fat interface](http://www.oodesign.com/interface-segregation-principle.html):

```
class GroupableUser implements IGrouppableUser {
     private $isGrouppable = true; // default, can be changed at runtime

     public function join(...) {
         if (!$this->isGrouppable) throw new Exception("User is not grouppable!");

         // real implementation
     }
}
```

The main disadvantage of this approach is that it makes the class `User` appear to unconditionally support a wide range of operations when in fact it does not and as a result can make coding tedious and error-prone (lots of `try`/`catch`). It might be OK if the vast majority of users support the vast majority of operations.

### Dynamic approach #1: behaviors

It would be much better to conditionally allow `User` instances to participate in these operations. This means that you need to be able to dynamically attach "behaviors" to `User` objects, which is fortunately quite easy to do in a dynamically typed language.

I suggest looking up a "behaviors" implementation from an established open-source project, but here's a quick and dirty example:

**Behavior base class and sample implementation**

```
abstract class Behavior {
    public function provides($name) {
        return method_exists($this, $name);
    }

    public function invoke($target, $name, $arguments) {
        array_unshift($arguments, $target);
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $name), $arguments);
    }
}

class GrouppableBehavior extends Behavior {
    public function join(User $user, $groupName) {
        echo "The user has joined group $groupName.";
    }
}
```

**Composable (can use behaviors) base class and User implementation**

```
class Composable {
    private $behaviors = array();

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        foreach ($this->behaviors as $behavior) {
            if ($behavior->provides($name)) {
                return $behavior->invoke($this, $name, $arguments);
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("No method $name and no behavior that implements it");
    }

    public function attach($behavior) {
        $this->behaviors[] = $behavior;
    }
}

class User extends Composable {}
```

**Test driver**

```
$user1 = new User;
$user2 = new User;

$user1->attach(new GrouppableBehavior);
$user1->join('Test Group'); // works
$user2->join('Test Group'); // throws
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/Y8NqKo)**.

The main disadvantages of this approach are that it consumes more runtime resources and that behaviors can only access `public` members of the classes they are attaching to. In some cases you may find yourself forced to expose an implementation detail that should be private to enable a behavior to work.

### Dynamic approach #2: decorators

A variation on behaviors is the [decorator pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html):

```
interface IUser {}

interface IGrouppableUser extends IUser {
    public function join(...);
}

class User implements IUser {}

class UserGroupingDecorator implements IGrouppableUser {
    private $realUser;

    public function __construct(IUser $realUser) {
        $this->realUser = $realUser;
    }

    public function join(...) { /* implementation */ }

    /* now you need to implement all IUser methods 
       and forward the calls to $this->realUser */

    /* if IUser exposes bare properties we have a problem! */
}
```

Using this pattern you can create a `UserGroupingDecorator` that wraps an `IUser` at will and pass the decorator to anything that accepts either an `IUser` or an `IGrouppableUser`.

The main disadvantage of this approach is that it also does not provide access to the non-public members of `User`. In addition it rules out exposing bare properties from `IUser` as there is no way to "forward" bare property accesses from `UserGroupingDecorator` to `$realUser` if the properties are also defined on the former -- and you cannot implement `IGrouppableUser` unless they are indeed defined. This state of affairs can be sidestepped by exposing properties as distinct getter/setter methods, but that means still more code to write.

Comment: Did you forget to write an example?

Comment: @evodevo: I was typing it up :)

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for

Comment: Wouldn't it be better performance-wise to implement behaviors using php traits?

Comment: @evodevo: You cannot, because traits are a compile-time mechanism while behaviors at runtime. But please read the answer again, I have just finished expanding it greatly.

Comment: Static approach is not suitable in my case, I have modular design, therefore User class can't know in advance what modules will extend its behavior

Comment: Decorators with traits seem to be the best choice so far. Do behaviors have any advantages over decorators? It seems that decorators are always the best choice since they consume less runtime resources than behaviors.

Comment: @evodevo: Actually that was a horrible blunder on my part. You cannot reuse a trait between `User` and `SomeKindOfUserDecorator`; the decorator needs to forward, while `User` needs to actually implement.

Comment: @evodevo: There are also other differences, e.g. behaviors can have state that affects the composable object (since it knows about its behaviors, it can query them) while decorators cannot achieve the same effect.

Comment: -1: this is a collection of thing's i would suggest not to do.

Comment: @tereško: It would be interesting to hear why

Answer (score 7):

You can't seem to be able to find a way to name the classes because the hierarchy is not very natural. In reality a user may participate in more than one group and each group may have more than one user. But a user may exist without a group, while there can't be a group without a user. I would say this means users should be a member of a group and `addUser` and `removeUser` should be placed in `Group`. Why? Because a user may not even "know" that he may join or leave a group and be perfectly happy, while there can not be a group that does not "know" that a user may join it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are open to join groups and groups where you request an invitation. `addUser` would indicate that a user is actually added to a group not that an invite request has been sent

Comment: Again knowledge which users are invited to join the group should be in the group, not in the user. Even if a user decides he is invited to join a group, this will make no difference if the group thinks otherwise.

Comment: But it's not a good design for the system to search all groups before knowing which one the user has invites pending.

Comment: What about `acceptInvitation`? This seems to belong to a user.

Comment: @evodevo this method may belong to both classes(maybe the descision is up to you) I believe at least I can't think of a reason to put it in one class or the other right now. Possibly I need more context for the business logic.

Comment: Very good answer! 1) Break the inheritance, since it does not make much sense here. Make them two independent classes. 2) Rename methods to addUser and removeUser; this simple change brings a lot of clarity to the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking in terms of a database-driven web app, I might do this with 5 classes:

1) User
2) Group
3) GroupAssignment
4) GroupInvitation
5) GroupInvitationRequest

Class 3 just maps one User to one Group.  Classes 4 and 5 are even more obvious.  This setup pretty much matches what you would have in a database anyway.  This allows for a good amount of flexibility, as a User could be a member of many groups (or one, or none).

EDIT:  Added additional classes based on new information in question.

Answer (score 0):

`Groupable` would be a good name for interface, Interface should describe an aspect of class, that might be required by instance of some different class. Interfaces are contract between classes.

Just don't stick the "I" in front of it, unless you use [hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) for **everything**. Simply use nouns for class names and adjectives for interfaces.

As for the name of class, I would go with:

```
class Participant extends User implements Groupable
{
    // methods that will be expected by from instance of this class
    // by any class that requires an object to have Groupable interfrace
}
```